# Access 2010 Audit Trail on SubForms

Tags: ms-access, vba, audit-trail, subforms

I am having trouble getting the code I found for an audit trail to work with sub forms. The origninal code is from http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut21.htm. I would rather stick to this code than using Allen Browne's code http://allenbrowne.com/appaudit.html. It seems to be a problem with `Screen.ActiveForm.Controls`. I have read that this does not work with sub forms. Is there a way I can alter this to audit a sub form in my database?

When I record the data in the sub form, I get the following error: Microsoft can't find the field "CalSubID" referred to in your expression."

In a module I have this code (this is just part of it that I think is having issues):

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Forms!Login!cboUser.Column(1)
Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
            .Update
        End With
End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Then in my "before update" and "AfterDelConfirm" events for the subform I have (where "CalSubID" is the PK for the subform and this is what the main module code uses to track the changes):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Call AuditChanges("CalSubID", "NEW")
Else
    Call AuditChanges("CalSubID", "EDIT")
End If
End Sub
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
If Status = acDeleteOK Then Call AuditChanges("CalSubID", "DELETE")
End Sub
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Modified Code:

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String

'added code
Dim SubFormName As String

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Forms!Login!cboUser.Column(1)

'msgbox to display name (just for now to test code)
MsgBox (" " & Screen.ActiveForm.Name & " ")

'IF THEN statement to check if user is using form with subform
If Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Cal Form" Then
SubFormName = "Cal Form Sub"

    Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm
            If ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then
            SubFormName = ctl.Name
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = SubFormName
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Forms![Screen.ActiveForm.Name]![SubFormName].Form![IDField].Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
'Getting error message at the --Next ctl-- line below, "next without for" message....
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = SubFormName
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Forms![Screen.ActiveForm.Name]![SubFormName].Form![IDField].Value
            .Update
        End With
        Set ctl = Nothing
End Select

Else

Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
            .Update
        End With
End Select


AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: What/where is "CalSubID"? And which line of code produces the error?

Comment: More complete code is needed. For example, where is your AuditChanges function. I see the function in the link but yours is necessary to see the resultset.

Comment: CalSubID is the PK for the table the sub form is connected to. The audit code runs off of the PK of a record. Other forums have postings of people with this same issue, everyone is saying that the Screen.ActiveForm does not work for sub forms. But no one has posted a fixes outside of using other forms of auditing. When the before update `If Then` statement runs, it errors out because the focus is not set to the sub form, therefore it is telling me that there is no PK called CalSubID because the focus is still set to the main form because of `Screen.ActiveForm.Controls`.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work? If you run into issues with the code below, feel free to ask for help.

Comment: Before adding in the code below, I want to clarify that this code will work in conjunction with the existing code which works fine for main forms. In a sense I want to have it check if the form is a sub form and if it is, run the code below, if not, continue with the standard existing code.

Comment: Also, I cannot get debug.print to display anything so I cannot figure out for 100% that this is the line that is not allowing the audit to work on subforms. I am merely basing this off of other forums where others have posted this exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming your error is with the line (it would help if you would verify):

```
![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
```

The issue as you've stated is that you can't access subform controls this way but must reference in this manner:

```
![RecordID] = Forms![main form name]![subform control name].Form![control name].Value
```

In your case, you need to first find the subform control name (presuming you only have 1 subform)

```
' Visit each control on the form
Dim ctl As Control
Dim SubFormName as string
SubFormName = ""
For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm
    If ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then
        SubFormName = ctl.Name
        exit for
    End If
Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing
```

Now in your code when setting RecordID, you can do it like this:

```
' you should check that SubFormName is not empty before this next line...
![RecordID] = Forms![Screen.ActiveForm.Name]![SubformName].Form![IDField].Value
```

I have not tested this and I'm a bit rusty on Access, so take the concept and fix the syntax.

** UPDATE** - Here is the code I would try with the new information you have provided. I am presuming that the controls (e.g. the one with ctl.Tag = "Audit") are all on the subform

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String

'added code
Dim SubFormName As String

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Forms!Login!cboUser.Column(1)

'msgbox to display name (just for now to test code)
MsgBox (" " & Screen.ActiveForm.Name & " ")

'IF THEN statement to check if user is using form with subform
If Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Cal Form" Then
  SubFormName = "Cal Form Sub"

    Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Forms![Cal Form]![Cal Form Sub].Form
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = SubFormName
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Forms![Cal Form]![Cal Form Sub].Form![IDField].Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = SubFormName
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Forms![Cal Form]![Cal Form Sub].Form![IDField].Value
            .Update
        End With
        Set ctl = Nothing
    End Select

Else

  Select Case UserAction
      Case "EDIT"
          For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
              If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                  If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                      With rst
                          .AddNew
                          ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                          ![UserName] = strUserID
                          ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                          ![Action] = UserAction
                          ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                          ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                          ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                          ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                          .Update
                      End With
                  End If
              End If
          Next ctl
      Case Else
          With rst
              .AddNew
              ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
              ![UserName] = strUserID
              ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
              ![Action] = UserAction
              ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
              .Update
          End With
  End Select
End If

AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
    End Sub
```

Comment: If I were to put an `If Then` statement after the `Case "EDIT"` to check if the user is on the form with the sub form then your above script would run, else, continue with original script? Or is my logic here all wrong? And yes, this is the only sub form in the database. Ironically enough, it is also the most critical form that needs the auditing the most.

Comment: Yes that would work fine. If you always know the name of the form wirh the subdorm and don't need a generic procedure, the above code could also be simplified.

Comment: I will give it a try as soon as I have time and report back on my findings.

Comment: ok, so I had time to play around a little with this but I am wondering if this is a little over my head with my current knowledge of this more complex code. I have added my "modified" code to my original question and have added comments in it stating what I have done. I am getting an error message at one of the `Next ctl` lines and I am now somewhat confused on if I am even doing this correctly. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I've added **UPDATE** code with my post above. It presumes that the controls (e.g. the one with ctl.Tag = "Audit") are all on the subform. The error you were getting I believe was from a mismatched If/End If. I've tested this code and it should be closer to what you need. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, tested out your updated code, and all seems to go well until I click on a textbox in the sub form. I then get an error "Microsoft Access can't find the field 'Cal Form Sub' referred to in your expression.". I am not sure what reference (since there are several) that it is talking about. I do know that it starts after the IF statement because my message box displaying the main form's name works properly. I would think it would be my first instance of the "Cal Form Sub"?

Comment: Why does clicking on the textbox trigger code to run? What code runs with the OnClick event? Make sure the Cal Form Sub does not have quotes around it. To debug set a breakpoint in your code. Highlight the first IF statement and press (F9) - the line of code should turn RED. Then duplicate the click on the textbox. When the code runs, it will stop on the RED line. Then press F8 to step through your code line by line until you find which line is failing. Alternately, you can F9 (set breakpoints) on all the lines with 'Cal Form Sub' and see which one it is. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: There is no OnClick event code. I think it is because when I click on the first text box on the sub form, it activates the form placing it as the active form? Just my guess. The Cal Form Sub does have quotes around it in the code `SubFormName = "Cal Form Sub"` which is the first instance of the name. I will try the debug method and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, so once it gets to the first `Case "EDIT"` it jumps to the first `case else` statement and cycles though. Once it finishes the `.update` it jumps to the `AuditChanges_Err:` section, displaying the error "Microsoft Access can't find the field 'Cal Form Sub' referred to in your expression." So, it jumping to the `case else` is ok since the entry on the form is a new entry, not an edit. It must be having an issue with the `![RecordID] = Forms![Cal Form]![Cal Form Sub].Form![IDField].Value` part.

Comment: ALso, when I hover the mouse oven this recordID code it shows "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Comment: What is difficult at this point is not having your actual forms - I need to know which fields are on which forms. Please clarify which form has tag = "Audit" and which form has the field "CalSubID".

Comment: Both the main form and sub form have "Audit" in the tag field in the properties menu so that the audit code monitors changes/additions to both forms. the CalSubID is the PK for the table that the sub form is bound to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59442/discussion-between-mseifert-and-mgogan).

Comment: Just for others who see this thread the problem is fixed. It was a total rookie mistake. I was going off of the "name" I gave the form in the navigation list to the left, and not the name given in the "caption" box in the form's properties sheet. So now it is obtaining the correct name and this error has gone away. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a much simpler solution. You need to pass the (sub)form object along to the main *basAudit* sub.

Now, becuase the subform is the one initiating the command, **it** will be passed along to *basAudit* sub instead of the *ActiveForm* (wich is the main form, not the subform).

Modify the *basAudit* module as followed:

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String, UsedForm As Form)
    On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim datTimeCheck As Date
    Dim strUserID As String
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    datTimeCheck = Now()
    strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
    Select Case UserAction
        Case "EDIT"
            For Each ctl In UsedForm.Controls
                If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                    If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                        With rst
                            .AddNew
                            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                            ![UserName] = strUserID
                            ![FormName] = UsedForm.Name
                            ![Action] = UserAction
                            ![RecordID] = UsedForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                            ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                            ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                            ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                            .Update
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next ctl
        Case Else
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserName] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = UsedForm.Name
                ![Action] = UserAction
                ![RecordID] = UsedForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                .Update
            End With
    End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Change the *AfterDelConfirm* sub as followed:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    If Status = acDeleteOK Then Call AuditChanges("Site", "DELETE", Form)
End Sub
```

And last, change the *BeforeUpdate* sub as followed:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Call AuditChanges("Site", "NEW", Form)
    Else
        Call AuditChanges("Site", "EDIT", Form)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this!

Each form has code to write changes to a table.
The Audit Trail gets a bit tricky when you lose `Screen.ActiveForm.Controls` as the reference - which happens if you use a Navigation Form.

It is also using **Sharepoint** lists so I found that none of the published methods were available.

I (often) use a form in the middle as a display layer and I find it has to fire the Form_Load code in the next forms down the line as well. 
Once they are open they need to be self sustaining.

Module Variable;

```
Dim Deleted() As Variant


Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'Audit Trail - New Record, Edit Record
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strTbl As String

    Dim strSub As String
    strSub = Me.Caption & " - BeforeUpdate"
    If TempVars.Item("AppErrOn") Then
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    strTbl = "tbl" & TrimL(Me.Caption, 6)
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblzzAuditTrail WHERE DateTime = #" & Now() & "#;"
    Set rst = dbLocal.OpenRecordset(strSql)

    For Each ctl In Me.Detail.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                If Me.NewRecord Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        !DateTime = Now()
                        !UserID = TempVars.Item("CurrentUserID")
                        !ClientID = TempVars.Item("frmClientOpenID")
                        !RecordID = Me.Text26
                        !ActionID = 1
                        !TableName = strTbl
                        !FieldName = ctl.ControlSource
                        !NewValue = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                Else
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        !DateTime = Now()
                        !UserID = TempVars.Item("CurrentUserID")
                        !ClientID = TempVars.Item("frmClientOpenID")
                        !RecordID = Me.Text26
                        !ActionID = 2
                        !TableName = strTbl
                        !FieldName = ctl.ControlSource
                        !NewValue = ctl.Value
                        !OldValue = ctl.OldValue
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3265
        Resume Next 'Item not found in recordset
        Case Else
        'Unexpected Error
        MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & _
        Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Source: " & strSub & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & _
        Err.Description, vbExclamation, "An Error has Occured!"
    End Select
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strTbl As String

    strTbl = "tbl" & TrimL(Me.Caption, 6)
    If Me.Preferred.Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot Delete Preferred Address." & vbCrLf & "Set Another Address as Preferred First.", vbOKOnly, "XXX Financial."
        Cancel = True
    End If

    ReDim Deleted(2, 1)
    For Each ctl In Me.Detail.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
 '       Debug.Print ctl.Name
            If ctl.Name <> "State" And ctl.Name <> "Pcode" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> "" Then
                  Deleted(0, i) = ctl.ControlSource
                  Deleted(1, i) = ctl.Value
'                  Debug.Print Deleted(0, i) & ", " & Deleted(1, i)
                  i = i + 1
                  ReDim Preserve Deleted(2, i)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strTbl As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strSub As String
    strSub = Me.Caption & " - AfterDelConfirm"
    If TempVars.Item("AppErrOn") Then
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    strTbl = "tbl" & TrimL(Me.Caption, 6)
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblzzAuditTrail WHERE DateTime = #" & Now() & "#;"
    Set rst = dbLocal.OpenRecordset(strSql)
'Audit Trail - Deleted Record
    If Status = acDeleteOK Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(Deleted, 2) - 1
            With rst
                .AddNew
                !DateTime = Now()
                !UserID = TempVars.Item("CurrentUserID")
                !ClientID = TempVars.Item("frmClientOpenID")
                !RecordID = Me.Text26
                !ActionID = 3
                !TableName = strTbl
                !FieldName = Deleted(0, i)
                !NewValue = Deleted(1, i)
                .Update
            End With
        Next i
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3265
        Resume Next 'Item not found in recordset
        Case Else
        'Unexpected Error
        MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & _
        Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Source: " & strSub & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & _
        Err.Description, vbExclamation, "An Error has Occured!"
    End Select
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```