# Record audit log from subform

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have form with a subform. Whenever someone changes a value in the subform the old record and the new record are recorded to an audit table. I have an additional field of a yes/no datatype on the subform. Its only purpose for being there is to be used for filtering on another form. Is there any way to write all the fields to the audit log except the yes/no field? Right now it records the entire record because the subform is bound to the table. But I do not want the yes/no field to be recorded along with the other fields. Let me know if you need to see any part of what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a qualifier in your write code on Type or Name or whatever you have;

```
If ctl.Type <> acCheckBox then
<Write to log>
end if


If FieldName <> "UnwantedCheckBox" then
<Write to log>
end if
```

I use this code in each form for total control;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737258/4411380

Comment: Thanks for that idea, Reuben! I was able to make it work with `Const oldVal as Byte = 0` in the Declarations section. Was able to get past the BeforeUpdate event but had a bit of trouble dodging the AfterUpdate event. Got it working, though, with an if statement comparing the checkbox value with `oldVal`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how you save the data from the subform to the audit table.

I assume you use bound textfields or combo-boxes or anything like that? If yes just unbound the yes/no-field.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Yes, the subform is bound to the table and there are 4 events used to create the audit logs (Before Update, After Update, On Delete, After Del Confirm ... the audit log code is not mine). The SQL statement used to insert the changed record on the log is an INSERT INTO (3 fields) SELECT (3 fields' values + table). But I don't want the entire table. I thought of unbinding, but when I did it created the "From" line and "To" line on the audit log without the Yes/No field but there is no difference between the lines. It should only record if the other fields are changed.