# Copy data from a subform into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am looking to copy records that I have edited in a sub form and put them into a new table I have created.

The sub form shows me all of my active jobs for a specific person and it has two fields on it so I can add my details beside the records. What I want to do is when i click save, I want only the records that have been edited to save into a table.

If you need anymore info let me know.

Would this be possible? What would I need to do to get this to work?

Many Thanks
Ethan

Comment: Please include what you have already tried to use to achieve this result.

Comment: I've only looked online for similar answers, other than that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well for starters, you are going to have to have a third field to write to. This field will need to be used for marking if the record has been edited. Upon saving you will have to write a query to check all records for that has_been_edited Value. Throw the result into a table, then reset all the records has_been_edited Value to false.

Comment: 1) Is the subform already bond to a table? 2) I assume from the description that not all subform records should be copied to the "new table", correct?  Only those that are "edited"?  3) The "two fields" for adding details -- are they bound to the subform recordset?  In other words, are they also part of the "active jobs" source? 4) Are the "two fields" supposed to re-load previously saved detail from the "new table"?  5) Also, are other fields besides the two detail fields editable?

Comment: 6)  How is the subform shown:  Single form, continuous form, datasheet?  If as single form, will it allow the datasheet view and do you expect it to function just the same?

Comment: If you want an audit log, review http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276803/access-2010-audit-trail-on-subforms) is specific to audit logs for subforms and the question also references the same link as June7.  The techniques outlined in both references will be helpful.  My questions are to deduce if Ethan wants more than an audit log, other functionality.  If only an Audit log is necessary, I think Data Macros provide a more robust, simple way of recording recordset changes and then it would work for all methods of changing a recordset without having to complicate form code.

Comment: Apologies if i haven't been too clear in my post. The subform is bound to a query that links 2 tables. (The subform is a datasheet). I have a combobox that allows me to filter the subform by person. So by doing this each person can go into the subform, change it to only show their jobs and add their predicted hours and comments beside some jobs. Once they have done this they will hit Save and close which will do just that but will also copy over the records that had data entered into them to an existing table . I hope this makes sense, thanks for all your input.

Comment: Just to add for the "Copy only if it has been edited" Part. Could I just add an IF statement, saying IF Hours is empty then don't copy the record?